# Run Excel Macro as part of SSIS task

Tags: excel, ssis

I've never done much heavy lifting with SSIS, only very simple stuff, so I hope you'll excuse my ignorance. I have a fairly simple package that pulls data from Excel into SQL Server. It works fine. My problem is that there is a macro in the Excel file that updates the data from, I believe, a web service. That's code I can't seem to access. My question then is this, can I use a script task to open the Excel file, run the macro, save it, and then import the data?

Ok, so before I posted the above question I went ahead and created a script task that should open the spreadsheet and run the macro. However, when I run it I get errors, the first being:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Version=14.0.0.0.0
```

Should I attack the problem a different way? Any suggestions? I sincerely appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: Nick. From the error, it looks like you are missing the primary Interop assemblies. What OS and what version of Office are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm running Server 2008 and Office 2007. I've done a lot of Excel work through C# and never run into this issue. The script seems to build ok, but I get the error when I try to run it.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install [The primary interop assemblies](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18346) on the machine where you are running the package. I am not sure if the License agreement allows you to install the Assembly on a server. This should resolve your issue hopefully.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Turns out that when I got rid of the reference to Excel version 14 and added 12 it appears to be working. Right now I'm still testing on my development machine. I'll move it over and see how it works on the real thing. Excel 2010 is installed on that machine.